# Kotlin: How to check if a mutabeListOf<Pair<Object, Int>> already contains a specific Object?

Tags: list, kotlin, comparison

I want to check if a `mutableListOf<Pair<Product, Int>>` already contains a product with a specific name. If there is a `Pair<Product, Int>` with the searched name, the Int value of this product should be increased.

Here is my approach:

```
fun main() {
    val item = Item()
    
    val prod1 = Product("Test")
    val prod2 = Product("Test")

    item.addProduct(prod1, 1)
    item.addProduct(prod2, 5)

   for ((prod,amount) in item) println("$Productname: {prod.productName}, $amount")
}
```

The Output should be:

> Productname: Test, 6

and not:

> Productname: Test, 1
>
> Productname: Test, 5

Here the Product Class:

```
class Product(val productName: String) {
    // other stuff that is unnecessary for the question
}
```

And the Item Class:

```
class Item {
    private val pairList = mutableListOf<Pair<Product, Int>>()

    fun addProduct(product: Product, quantity: Int) {
        for (prod in pairList) {
            if (pairList.contains(Pair(product, quantity))){
                val value = prod.second + quantity
                prod.copy(second = value)
            } else {
                pairList.add(Pair(product, quantity))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, nothing works (neither the comparison nor adding a new Pair). I appreciate every post!

Comment: Your `Product` class needs to define an `equals' method, otherwise 2 instances will never compare equal. You might want to use a `data class` in case the equality is just compraring a set of fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there are two possibilities depending on your needs.

**1. Use `MutableMap<Product, Int>`**

This is a perfect use-case to use a `MutableMap<K, V>` instead of `MutableList<Pair<K, V>>` since you need to find the current quantity for a given product and increase it:

```kotlin
private val productMap = mutableMapOf<Product, Int>()

fun addProduct(product: Product, quantity: Int) {
    val foundQuantity = productMap[product]
    // Increase the found quantity by [quantity] or add the given [quantity].
    val finalQuantity = foundQuantity?.let { it + quantity } ?: quantity
    productMap[product] = finalQuantity
}
```

To do this, you should make your `Product` class a `data class` (or implement manually `equals` and `hashcode`) to be able to compare the hash of two `Product`s using their `productName` value.

```kotlin
data class Product(val productName: String) { ... }
```

The pros of this solution are the fast lookups and the fast insertions.
The cons of this solution is that your products won't be sorted anymore.

**2. Use `MutableList<Pair<Product, Int>>`**

If you need your products sorted and you need to maintain the same insertion order, you can still use a list making some optimizations.

```kotlin
private val pairList = mutableListOf<Pair<Product, Int>>()

fun addProduct(product: Product, quantity: Int) {
    pairList.forEachIndexed { index, (savedProduct, savedQuantity) ->
        if (savedProduct.productName == product.productName) {
            // This is the product we are searching for.
            pairList[index] = product to quantity + savedQuantity
            // We found the product and replaced it, we don't need to search for it anymore.
            return
        }
    }
    // We didn't find a product, add it as the last item.
    pairList += product to quantity
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works, thank you. But I have two questions. 1. how does this ```pairList[index] = product to quantity + savedQuantity``` work and 2. Why did you write ```return```?

Comment: 1. `pairList[index] = product to quantity + savedQuantity` it's the short way to say `pairList.set(index, Pair(product, quantity + savedQuantity))` because the `[ ] =` is the operator fun `set` and because `to` is an `infix` extension function used to create a `Pair`. 2. the return is used to avoid to loop on all the list if the product was found before than the last element and also to avoid to add a new `Pair` to the list in the last instruction.

Comment: ah okay, thank you very much. And ```pairList += product to quantity``` is the short version of: ```pairList.add(Pair(product, quantity))``` yes? And is it possible to replace the ```return``` with ```break```?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No, you can't replace it with `break` in my example, since if you use `break`, it will exit from the loop but it will also executes the last instruction which adds another product to the list (so you'd have the same product twice).

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks. Ain't there another way than writing an empty return statement? I have to explain my code, and I am not that convenient about that empty return statement. F

Comment: @Andrew let's move this to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212498/giorgio-antoniolis-chat